# How can two Android applications share same Linux user ID and share same VM?

Tags: android

I observed it while exploring 2 apps my friend made. How can two Android applications share the same Linux user ID and share same VM?

Answer (score 1):

You can run them in the same process.  You just need to assign same values to `android:sharedUserId` and `android:process` in both applications and sign them with same certificate.

From the Android docs

> android:process
>
> The name of a process where all components of the
>   application should run. Each component can override this default by
>   setting its own process attribute. By default, Android creates a
>   process for an application when the first of its components needs to
>   run. All components then run in that process. The name of the default
>   process matches the package name set by the  element.
>
> By setting this attribute to a process name that's shared with another
>   application, you can arrange for components of both applications to
>   run in the same process — but only if the two applications also share
>   a user ID and be signed with the same certificate.
>
> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a
>   new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed.
>   If the process name begins with a lowercase character, a global
>   process of that name is created. A global process can be shared with
>   other applications, reducing resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to arrange for two apps to share the same Linux user ID, in which case they are able to access each other's files.

To conserve system resources, apps with the same user ID can also arrange to run in the same Linux process and share the same VM.

The apps must also be signed with the same certificate.

More details at this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals).